# Get User's ID for inserting into a lookup field

Tags: sharepoint-online

So I can use the `PeopleManager` to get a user's profile but I can't figure out how to get the correct ID I need in order to add a new list item to a list and populate a look-up type field with that specific user's information.

After an item is inserted I can get that value using the `FieldUserValue` but how do I determine it before?

This is using COM in C# and SharePoint 2013 Online.

Answer (score 0):

From a COM solution you can fetch data of the User's only by

```
/site/test/_vti_bin/userprofileservice.asmx
```

web service. So you can user the following code to fetch data:

```
  UserProfileService tmpUserProfileService = new UserProfileService();
  tmpUserProfileService.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("ADMIN", "PASSWORD", "DOMAIN");
  PropertyData[] properties =tmpUserProfileService.GetUserProfileByName(@"DOMAIN\USER");            
  for (int i = 0; i < properties.Length; i++)
  {
       Console.WriteLine(properties[i].Name);
       Console.WriteLine(properties[i].Value);
  }
  Console.Read();
```

> Reference: [User Profile Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms550407%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: I can already do that in COM to get a person's profile but there is no ID field for me to grab in order to set a field (say creating a new list item) to be a specific person in a person picker field.

I've tried using the ID I have, which isn't a domain\user its something else (this is sharepoint online)

It seems I can set a person picker type field in a list using only this ID, I've tried using the GUIDs, the ID I use to get the profile, and some other stuff.

Maybe I am going abot trying to set that field when I create a new list item wrong?